# Rank 3 Tensor Multiplication Memory issue

Tags: performance-tuning

I'm doing a complicated tensor multiplication experiment. 
Imaging there are two Rank 3 tensors generated as below:

```
ten0 = Table[g, {T+1}];
ten1 = Table[g, {2 T + 1}];
```

where g and dimension T are:

```
g := RandomComplex[10 + 5 I, {120, 120}];
T = 50;
```

I want to oragnize two tensors to a new `{T+1,2T+1}` tensor as:

```
tensorT = Table[ten0[[i]]*ten1[[j]], {i, T+1}, {j, 2 T + 1}];
```

And then multiply it to a matrix whose dimension is also `{T+1,2T+1}`:

```
mat = RandomComplex[10 + 5 I, {T+1, 2 T + 1}];
```

and calculate the sum:

```
Total[mat*tensorT, 2];
```

I got memory crash when I try to increase the dimension T to higher values. And the time efficiency is compared low.

```
 MemoryInUse[]/2^30.
 (*1.18938 GB*)
```

I was trying to research the issue and assuming MMA might be doing a "copied" passing thing in memory. [see post here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/115087/speedup-matrix-number-multiplication). So large matrix multiplications will generate this issue.

So I have tried to use `Developer'ToPackedArray@` to those tensors but there is no difference.

And I managed to solve the memory issue by using DOUBLE `Do` loop instead:

```
mat0 = Table[0. + I 0., {i, 120}, {j, 120}];
Do[Do[mat0 = 
mat0 + (mat[[n + 1]][[m + T + 1]])*ten0[[n + 1]]*
 ten1[[m + T + 1]], {m, -T, T}], {n, 0, T}]
mat0
```

But as you might think, it's even slower which is not acceptable to me.

I have been stuck here for days. Could you please offer some advice?

Comment: This code worked for me. Mma eats  about 5 Gb of memory, though WolframKernel.exe takes only about 1.3 Gb.

Comment: yes, for smaller T it will work. But I hope to increase it to 200 or more than that.

Comment: Why not at once  `tensorT = 
  Table[ten0[[i]]*ten1[[j]] RandomComplex[10 + 5 I], {i, T + 1}, {j, 
    2 T + 1}];`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The important idea is to avoid `tensorT` being built explicitly.

Buliding the tensors in a way that ansure that they are packed arrays (avoiding `Table`):

```
n = 120;
T = 50;
ten0 = RandomComplex[10 + 5 I, {T + 1, n, n}];
ten1 = RandomComplex[10 + 5 I, {2 T + 1, n, n}];
mat = RandomComplex[10 + 5 I, {T + 1, 2 T + 1}];
```

The actual computation:

```
AbsoluteTiming[MaxMemoryUsed[
  tensorT = Table[ten0[[i]]*ten1[[j]], {i, T + 1}, {j, 2 T + 1}];
  a = Total[mat*tensorT, 2];
  ]]
AbsoluteTiming[MaxMemoryUsed[
  b = Total[ten0 mat.ten1];
  ]]
Max[Abs[a - b]]
```

> {2.90361, 2373581208}
>
> {0.016172, 23501216}
>
> 7.00913*10^-10

Comment: Yes, this works, Thanks a lot!

Comment: You're welcome.